Express JS - static images fail to load with res.redirect
I have static images served from public folder. If I have
const getSomeController = (req, res, next) => {
    res.send(htmlFunction)
}

const postSomeController = (req, res, next) => {
    res.redirect('/path/to/getSomeController)
}

If I access the URL via the GET request, the images will always load. If I use the post request, at the end of which it redirects to the GET controller, none of the static images on the page load. However images not on the file system, for instance from another website, will load straight away.
I have tested it on FireFox/Chrome/Edge and there is a difference in behaviour.
Firefox on localhost throttles the page, even though throttling is off, this delays the response and Firefox does load the images.
Chrome/Edge navigate to the page instantly and end up getting this response:
(failed)net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
If you add throttling to the Chrome/Edge, it will load the images.
If you add Fast 4G, it will load the images, but inbetween a white page will load with no UI stating the Server has not sent a response, before redirecting and loading the new URL
If you add Slow 4g, it will linger on the current page before redirecting, which is a better experience as you do not see the white page from browser stating a response was not sent.
The images are served from public folder in a subfolder 'images' like so
app.use(express.static(path.join(import.meta.dirname, 'public')));
And the path of the images is saved as abolute like so
/images/filename.png
The directory on FS is like so
public/images/filename.png
The request initiator chain in network tools ends with
http://localhost:3000/images/filename.png
So to recap, no issues when using res.send.
Fails to work on res.redirect, unless you throttle the browser to slow it down, Firefox throttles automatically so it always works.
changing headers/throttling browsers/
Cannot find reference to this on google.
AI in this matter is useless.
I prefer not to have to replace redirect with a copy of res.send and the entire function and variables to send, as res.redirect makes things simpler, but not if it will have this fatal issue.

Partly why throttling helps is because when you use a server-side redirect (res.redirect()), the browser immediately stops processing the current request and starts a new one for the redirected URL. This behavior can lead to pending asset requests (like images) being canceled or not fully processed, especially if the redirect happens too quickly.
If you need to retain 302 redirect, I'd rather move the redirect to the front-end side and work with the browser directly there, allowing it to wait for assets better than in the case of server-side redirect here.
Call your POST endpoint receive response and redirect from the client-side.
Let me know if that solves the issue

I am currently learning Node Express, and the current app will remain a server-side app without a separate frontend app. So, I think in order to do that, I would need to do a res.send that sends some kind of function, which uses the client to redirect.
I did, however, find a solution that, so far after testing, seems to work:
app.use(express.static(path.join(import.meta.dirname, 'public'), {
  maxAge: '1d',
  etag: false
}));

Oh, interesting. That is, indeed, a good way to handle it too.
